# R: why, how to avoid: read.table turns character (strings) to numeric by removing last character (colon)

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, import, export-to-csv

Have a dataframe which I want to export to CSV and re-import to dataframe. When importing one column is corrupted -- by removing the colon from the end of the strings, and interpreting them as numeric.

Here a minimal example:

```
df <- data.frame(integers = c(1:8, NA, 10L),
                 doubles  = as.numeric(paste0(c(1:7, NA, 9, 10), ".1")),
                 strings = paste0(c(1:10),".")
                 )
df
str(df) # here the last column is "chr"

write.table(df,
            file = "df.csv",
            sep = "\t",
            na = "NA",
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = TRUE,
            fileEncoding = "UTF-8",
)

df <- read.table(file = "df.csv",
                 header = TRUE,
                 sep = "\t",
                 na.strings = "NA",
                 quote="\"",
                 fileEncoding = "UTF-8"
                 )
df
str(df)  # here the last column is "num"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `read.table`, we can specify the `colClasses` specified in `?vector`

> The atomic modes are "logical", "integer", "numeric" (synonym "double"), "complex", "character" and "raw".

The issues is that `?read.table` `colClasses` uses `type.convert` if not specified to automatically judge the type of the column

> Unless colClasses is specified, all columns are read as character columns and then converted using type.convert to logical, integer, numeric, complex or (depending on as.is) factor as appropriate.

The relevant code in `read.table` would be

```
...
     do[1L] <- FALSE
    for (i in (1L:cols)[do]) {
        data[[i]] <- if (is.na(colClasses[i])) 
            type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, 
                numerals = numerals, na.strings = character(0L))
        else if (colClasses[i] == "factor") 
            as.factor(data[[i]])
        else if (colClasses[i] == "Date") 
            as.Date(data[[i]])
        else if (colClasses[i] == "POSIXct") 
            as.POSIXct(data[[i]])
        else methods::as(data[[i]], colClasses[i])
    }
...
```

```
df <- read.table(file = "df.csv",
                 header = TRUE,
                 sep = "\t",
                 na.strings = "NA",
                 quote="\"",
                 fileEncoding = "UTF-8", 
           colClasses = c("integer", "numeric", "character")
                 )
```

-checking the struture

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ integers: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 NA 10
 $ doubles : num  1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1 6.1 7.1 NA 9.1 10.1
 $ strings : chr  "1." "2." "3." "4." ...
```

Comment: ... However, isn't it strange that it "deletes" the colon, and by doing so it looses the only hint that it could be a character string? If you inspect the `df.csv` manually you see that the elements of the last column are sourrounded by quotes.

Comment: @alex where did you added the colon

Comment: @alex did you meant `c(1:10)`, it is a `seq` creating a integer

Comment: If you take a texteditor and open the `df.csv` file, you see that the last column is of the form `"x."` (where x is a number). Being inside quotation marks should be a reasonable hint for the parser NOT to transform the (explicit) strings inside into something else. So why is `read.table` ignoring this?

Comment: @alex It is just that it calls `type.convert` i.e. `type.convert(c("1.", "2."), as.is = TRUE)#[1] 1 2`

Comment: @alex I updated with the lines in read.table that calls `type.convert`

Comment: Motivation: In German language `10.` is similar to the english `10th` -- it indicates the *ordinality*. So it is -- even if in this case can be easily fixed -- important to distiguish between a number and it's ordinal cousin.

Comment: @alex I understand, but `.` is also part of the `numeric`.  If you had another character i.e. `:` or so, it would parse as character

Comment: @alex if you notice the `type.convert` syntax is specifies the `dec = "."`. You may change it, but then the whole function should be changed, i.e. `type.convert` is not an input argument in `read.table`.  You may have to change the body of the function

Comment: Thank you very much again. I already accepted the answer. Have an nice day (-: